# gradle unable to fetch c3p0 dependency

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, gradle, c3p0

I am trying to create ComboPooledDataSource which is ideally present in C3P0 dependency. despite adding the gradle compile group, and doing gradle clean build, it is unable to fetch the jars related to c3p0. Below is the **build.gradle** file

```
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
    }

    group = 'com.xyz.abc'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

    configurations {
        developmentOnly
        runtimeClasspath {
            extendsFrom developmentOnly
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    ext {
        set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.RELEASE")
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.10.Final'
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '5.2.10.Final'
        compile group: 'com.mchange', name: 'c3p0', version: '0.9.5.2'
        runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        }
    }   
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using gradle `build --refresh-dependencies` and see if it is able to download or not.
Also if you are working in a company where you need to download dependencies from a central repo, please check if that version of the dependency is present

Comment: yes, I tried to execute that. no luck yet again!